A centre of a simple closed planar curve
Let $c: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a continuous planar curve such that $c(0)=c(1)$. I was wondering if there is a way to find something like a "centre of mass" of planar curve $c$.
One prospective weak definition of a centre I have in mind is a point $\vec{p}$ such that any contraction of the plane about $\vec{p}$, i.e. $\vec{x} \mapsto \vec{p}+t(\vec{x} - \vec{p})$ where $t \in (0,1)$ maps $c$ to a curve which does not intersect $c$. Such a definition does give rise to multiple centres for some curves like a circle, but I'm interested in whether such a centre can exist for every simple closed curve $c$.
Maybe we could get the average $x$ coordinate and average $y$ coordinate of $c$ by integrating along the $x$ and $y$ components of $c$ respectively, but we may not always be able to integrate; for instance if $c$ is the Koch snowflake. Besides I have no clue if we can prove this centre satisfies the above definition. I would thus appreciate any ideas on how to find such a centre, or even alternate definitions of a centre.
Full disclosure, I wanted to use such a centre in proving the Jordan Curve Theorem as the centre should always lie in the bounded component of the curve, but I would also appreciate an answer assuming the Jordan Curve Theorem to sate my curiosity.
Edit: As @ChrisLewis pointed out, the centre of mass obtained by integrating can in fact lie in the unbounded component of the curve and thus does not always satisfy the above definition of a centre. However I would still like to know if the centre defined above exists for every simple closed planar curve.

I'm a little confused by your proposed definition, but it might be worth noting that the calculation you mention (average $x$ and $y$ coordinates of points along the curve, ie the centroid of the curve) can lie "outside" or on the curve itself: for example, if you trace around a letter "C" to form a closed curve, its centroid lies outside. If $\overrightarrow{p}$ lies on $c$ itself, will that violate the definition?

Centroid & Barycenter & Center of gravity & Center of Mass are very commonly used terms for what you want.
Using the techniques involved there & taking the curve to have "Constant Density" , we can make this Intuitive Definition for Center :
We can consider taking a Point $A$ on the curve & connecting it with a line to Point $B$ on the other side of the curve such that Curve Segment $AB$ is half of the total curve length.
Now , we can consider taking a Point $C$ on the curve & connecting it with a line to Point $D$ on the other side of the curve such that Curve Segment $CD$ is half of the total curve length.
Intersection of $\overline{AB}$ & $\overline{CD}$ is the Center of the curve.
This will work out well for normal curves like Circle , Ellipse , Square , Pentagon.
Even exotic curves like Koch Snowflake will work out well with a little care.

